# How to display an html code(which parsed xml) on android application

Tags: android, html, xml, web-services

I am an android developer. I'm calling web service for one functionality and getting following code as output, when the web service is called.

```
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<Response>
<Response_Code>0</Response_Code>
<Response_Description></Response_Description>
<Description></Description>
</Response>
</string>
```

In between the Description tag i get html code.
I want to display this on android app.
Can anybody tell me, how i can do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the following code as taken from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html
and use a webview to display the data as:

```
String summary =<WHATEVER IS IN YOUR DESCRIPTION TAG> ;
webview.loadData(summary, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the Html class.

```
someTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(descriptionText));
```